# pylucene with python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, lucene, pylucene

I have a virtual environment with python 3.4.3. I want to install pylucene for this environment.

How can I do that? Or can I somehow still run pylucene if I use the python from my virtual environment?

I couldn't find any info on python 3 support on http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/install.html
and if I follow the instructions, I'm getting syntax error on the phase of JCC installation as the code is expected to be run with python 2.x.

Answer (score 5):

Updated answer: PyLucene 6.5.0 is now officially ported to python3. http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/

I have ported `jcc` and `pylucene` to python3

First install `jcc` from here:
https://github.com/rudimeier/jcc

Then `pylucene` from here:
https://github.com/rudimeier/pylucene

The pylucene repository contains 3 ported versions (3.x, 4.x and 6.x) in different branches.

Comment: @ziyuang  upstream has now officially released  PyLucene 6.5.0 with python3 support. http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/

Answer (score 3):

PyLucene doesn't currently support Python 3;  [it's unclear if it will](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-pylucene-dev/201506.mbox/%3Calpine.OSX.2.01.1506010952020.53725@yuzu.local%3E).

Comment: thanks @Coady... I'm now thinking how can I use lucene in my virtual environment with python 3